# How can I validate custom annotation attributes?

Tags: java, spring

I have one custom field annotation class with two attributes like below:

```
public @interface Field {
    String type();
    int order();
}
```

I wanted to validate `order`, it should not be a negative value and should not repeat, for example:

```
class User {
    @Field(uiType = "TEXT", order = 1)
    private String fName;

    @Field(uiType = "TEXT", order = 2)
    private String lName;
}
```

Can anyone help me to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to ensure variables are returned in a specific order during reflection? Please give more info on problem.

Comment: Use Java`s [apt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html), Annotation Processing Tool. For compile time checks. [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this isn't quite what the Bean Validation API is for, you can perform this validation with it. I'm assuming you'd use [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), the reference implementation of the BV API.

You can get the negative check out of the way using a simple validator. Modify @Field to

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyFieldValidator.class)
public @interface Field {
    String type();
    int order();
}
```

and create a `MyFieldValidator` class as follows

```
public class MyFieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Field, Object> {

    private int order;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Field annotation) {

        this.order = annotation.order();

        if (this.order < 0) {
          // blow up
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

If you then put the object through a validator, e.g. using `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(someUser)`, any negative order annotation attributes will fail.

Preventing repetition is trickier. The sanest option is to put a validation annotation at the `User` class level, then use reflection to get the annotations one by one. The advantage of using the class level annotation is that it gives you a simple way to tell Hibernate Validator which classes to check. The not-so-great part is that you might forget to annotate the class.

Comment: Thanks Emerson. I have done negative order validation as you described.

Comment: Glad it helped. You also tagged Spring in this question. If you don't want to do bean validation for the repetition check, another option is to create an @OrderedFields annotation and put it on User, and in some PostConstruct, call ApplicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(OrderedFields.class) to get the beans, iterate through the classes, and check the Field annotations with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

`ConstraintValidator` should help you.

- [More About](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html)

Comment: Please elaborate why this answers the question. think about adding link to documentation and maybe some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

As Philipp Sanders said you can use a singleton which runs a method at startup of the application context that uses reflection on a class. Thats for the validation part.

To get all classes in a given package implementing an interface, have an annotation or extend a class you can use the component scanner of spring.

Check out this link for a scanner possibility:

http://javaasylum.blogspot.fr/2011/05/annotation-scanner-with-spring.html?m=1

Answer (score -1):

you could write a validator that checks the values via reflection.
you run this validator at first in your application.

Comment: For this he'd have to manually validate each class right?  I've looked for a way to search all classes in a package for a class annotation with no success.

Comment: the reflection api helps you a lot

Comment: Yeah, but you don't know of a way to get a collection of all classes in a package dynamically do you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: So, third-party dependency required.